# Calling Another Function in a Recusive Function results in error. Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, visual-c++, c++14

I've two functions fun() and fun2();

fun() calls itself while incrementing the global variable a=0 and terminates if a==5. But if I call another function called fun2() which basically returns and do nothing, then Build Error happens. Why?
I'm just experimenting with recursion and I got this error.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a = 0;

void fun() {
    if (a == 5)
        return;
    a++;
    fun();
    fun2();  //This is where the trouble happens
}
        
void fun2() {
    return;
}

int main() {
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: The compiler reads from the top down. It doesn't know about the `fun2` function yet where you try to call it. Either move the definition above `fun` or add a prototype.

Comment: @RetiredNinja why does that?

Comment: You tagged this as C++, but used not one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get similar error with

```
void fun() {
    fun2(); 
}

void fun2() {}

int main() {
    fun();
}
```

The error is not related to the recursion. You need to delcare a function before you can call it:

```
#include<iostream>

void fun2();   // declaration

void fun() {
    // ...
    fun2();  
}

void fun2() { }  // definition

int main() {
    fun();

    return 0;
}
```

...or simply define `fun2` before `fun`.

Comment: @ALLAN it is impossible to remember everything, though I honestly wonder what was not clear about the error message

Comment: I'm just starting out. I 've to study to remember :)

Comment: @ALLAN  No matter how much you study you can never remember everything or avoid every mistake. Its more important to learn to read error messages, they are made for you to read and show you what is wrong in the code.

Comment: You do not 'always' need to declare or define functios before using them in c++.

Comment: @278558 can you show an example for waht you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You must declare or define functions before using them.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a = 0;
void fun2(); // add this (declaration of function fun2)
void fun() {
    if (a == 5)
        return;
    a++;
    fun();
    fun2();  //This is where the trouble happens
}

void fun2() {
    return;
}
int main() {
    fun();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not always in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> "why does that?"

Well, not because of recursion.

In this case, it does this partly because your code is c-style, which mostly does require declaration of user defined functions that your code calls.

---

You tagged this post with c++, but use not one class.

And, for example, if these functions were encapsulated in a class, then the c++ compiler will (usually) find the functions ... even with no prior declaration.

Example:

In the following, I have encapsulated your code inside a functor (a simplified c++ class)

And, because your code does no output, I've added cout's at locations to demonstrate, visually, that the code compiles and the functions are executed.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::cerr, std::endl, std::hex, std::dec, std::cin; 

#include <string>
using std::string, std::to_string;



int a = 0;  // still global, though many discourage use


// functor ... a simple class
class F705_t // ctor and dtor are compiler provided defaults
{
public:

// main() enters at this function
int operator()(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
  return exec(argc, argv);  // exec not yet declared!
}

private:

int exec(int , char** ) // line 31
{
  cout << "\n  F705_t::exec()";
  fun();   // using fun() before declared
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}

void fun() // line 37
{
  cout << "\n  F705_t::fun()" << "  a: " << a;

  if (a == 5)
    return;
  a++;
  fun();   // recursive call 
  fun2();  // using fun2() before declared
}
        
void fun2()  // line 47
{
  cout << "\n  F705_t::fun2()" << "  a: " << a;;
  return; 
}
} // class F705_t

// main() is a c-ism, 
// and is required of the user in most (but not all) c++ environments
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { return F705_t()(argc, argv); }
//           how invoke a functor --------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Output:

```
  F705_t::exec()
  F705_t::fun()  a: 0
  F705_t::fun()  a: 1
  F705_t::fun()  a: 2
  F705_t::fun()  a: 3
  F705_t::fun()  a: 4
  F705_t::fun()  a: 5
  F705_t::fun2()  a: 5
  F705_t::fun2()  a: 5
  F705_t::fun2()  a: 5
  F705_t::fun2()  a: 5
  F705_t::fun2()  a: 5
```